# How to download WWDC 2011 session_310__whats_new_in_instruments

Tags: safari

I can not download WWDC 2011 session_310 whats_new_in_instruments well. I do not know why.

Other WWDC sessions are downloaded as expected , As you can see

[image]

Any Tips?

I guess to inspect element and adjust JavaScript is OK.

Comment: What exactly is the error/problem here?

Comment: The data of the movie downloaded take wrong memory size. It costs only 10.7 M . It should cost hundreds M. So it played just the beginning well and went to black.

Comment: I can reproduce this, only downloads the first 1:30 of the video. It sounds like you've got a solution with ‘inspect element’? Feel free to provide it as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I try to inspect the html element

```
<a href="https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_310__whats_new_in_instruments.m4v"
onclick="s_objectID=&quot;
https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2011__hd/session_310__wha_1&quot;
;return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">

HD Video</a>
```

and fint the HD resource is demaged . So I downloaded the SD m4v.